# Create getter and setter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial to create getter and setter in Javascript, I have the code like this:

```
// Create a new User object that accept an object of properties
function User(properties) {
    // Iterate through the properties of the object, and make
    // sure it's properly scoped
    for (var i in properties) { (function(){
        // Create a new getter for the property
        this['get' + i] = function() {
            return properties[i];
        };

        // Create a new setter for the property
        this['set' + i] = function(val) {
            properties[i] = val;
        };
    })(); }
}

// Create a new User object instance and pass in an object of
// properties to seed it with
var user = new User({
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 28
});

// Just note that the name property does not exist, as it's private
// within the property object
console.log(user.name == null);

// However, we are able to access its value using the new getname()
// method, that was dynamically generated
console.log(user.getname());
```

However, console shows error saying user does not have method getname. The code is trying to dynamically generate getter and setter method, it looks ok to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your in-loop function is losing the `this`, do a `var t = this;` outside loop and refer to `t` inside.

Comment: You could also use [es5 getters/setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get).

Comment: Then you need to know that `i` as you use it in the getter/setter will always have the same value (i.e., the last value of the loop) for all getters/setters the code creates.

Comment: Why do you have an anonymous function in your for loop? What purpose does it serve? Are you populating from a web service?

Comment: @tjameson It's there for a reason. If it wasn't there than `i` would always be the last value. However he is using it wrong as your suppose to pass `i` as an argument to the function.

Comment: The anonymous function is used to make sure getting the correct i value, not the last one.

Comment: @Shawn31313 - Ah, I guess I overlooked what the getters were doing. I guess I'm not understanding why `properties` is being hidden, but that's not really related.

Comment: problem solved, Paul and Shawn has great solution below.

Comment: I gave you my getter/setter option as well for completeness.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? Can you post the relevant URL?

Answer (score 15):

The other answers are correct in that you need to pass `i` into your anonymous function, but you could also do this with [ES5 Getters and Setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get):

```
// Create a new User object that accept an object of properties
function User(properties) {
    var self = this; // make sure we can access this inside our anon function
    for (var i in properties) {
        (function(i) {
            Object.defineProperty(self, i, {
                // Create a new getter for the property
                get: function () {
                    return properties[i];
                },
                // Create a new setter for the property
                set: function (val) {
                    properties[i] = val;
                }
            })
        })(i);
    }
}
```

The benefit of using ES5 getters and setters is that now you can do this:

```
var user = new User({name: 'Bob'});
user.name; // Bob
user.name = 'Dan';
user.name; // Dan
```

Since they're functions, they modify the passed in `properties`, not just the object itself. You don't have to use `getN` or `setN` anymore, you can just use `.N`, which makes using it look more like accessing properties on an object.

This approach, however, isn't universally portable (requires IE 9+).

Here's what I'd probably do in practice though:

```
function User(properties) {
    Object.keys(properties).forEach(function (prop) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
            // Create a new getter for the property
            get: function () {
                return properties[prop];
            },
            // Create a new setter for the property
            set: function (val) {
                properties[prop] = val;
            }
        })
    }, this);
}
```

The above gets rid of your for loop. You're already using an anonymous function, so might as well get the most of it.

Comment: A nice side-effect is that you can't accidentally assign over the top: `user.setname = 'Dan'`. Not really a big issue, but I've seen people accidentally do that and wonder why their their code broke.

Comment: I've added what I consider to be better style. `for .. in` can cause weird problems (probably not in this case though), and I think Array.forEach is mor elegant anyway.

Comment: @tjameson ES5 getters and setters are great, but if you're doing nothing more than mirroring, I don't see the point over just using an _Object_.

Comment: @PaulS. This can be useful if you want to use `properties` wholesale later (e.g. upload to a server) without allowing extra properties to be attached. Maybe the OP has other properties on `User` that only make sense in the web app and not in a potentially later POST to the server. But I agree, the OP said nothing about why he/she wanted this.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a closure issue:

```
function User(properties) {
    // Iterate through the properties of the object, and make
    // sure it's properly scoped
    for (var i in properties) { 
        (function(i){
            // Create a new getter for the property
            this['get' + i] = function() {
                return properties[i];
            };

            // Create a new setter for the property
            this['set' + i] = function(val) {
                properties[i] = val;
            };
        }.call(this, i));
    }
}
```

Also, as @Paul pointed out, `this` was actually referring to the function which was contained in the for loop. Not the `User` function. I fixed that by using a call and assigning the `User` this to the function (no need for extra variable).

Comment: Thanks. This looks quite elegant. But I don't understand why using call works? What's the essence of 'call'?

Comment: `call` allows you to define `this`. `.call(this, i)` the `this` in the call function is referring to the `this` of the user function. That is then passed on to the function. It is equal to using something like `.bind(this)(i)`. Only difference is that `call` triggers the function and allows you to set the arguments within the function.

Comment: It's an issue with closures. I am the worst with explaining closures. If you wouldn't pass `i` to call to use it in the function. `i` would always equal the last property in the Object.

Comment: I thought the anonymous function already handled the 'last i' problem.

Comment: Well no, it doesn't fix it unless you pass `i` as an argument. Without passing argument: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/zU7cE/. With passing argument: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/zU7cE/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your in-loop function is losing the `this`, do a `var t = this`; outside loop and refer to `t` inside. Also, pass `i` into your function.

```
function User(properties) {
    var t = this, i;
    for (i in properties) (function (i) {
        t['get' + i] = function () { return properties[i]; };
        t['set' + i] = function (val) { properties[i] = val; };
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Thanks.